# rails surveyor gem example gets sass syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass, surveyor-gem

I'm installing the surveyor gem in a new (test) rails 3 project. I've run `rails g surveyor:install`, and `rake db:migrate`, and `rake surveyor FILE=surveys/kitchen_sink_survey.rb`
and then run `rails server`

It seems to "work" only the sass is not compiling correctly, so i get no styles and the page contains:

```
Syntax error: Invalid property: ":background-color= !background_color".
```

I'm running in Windows, with Ruby 1.9.2, the Gemfile contains

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.9'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'surveyor', :git => 'git://github.com/breakpointer/surveyor.git', :branch => 'rails3'
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'haml'
gem 'sass'
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
```

Comment: Same problem, super weird… the {gem_folder_path}/chriseppstein-compass-0.8.17frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/utilities/general/_reset.sass does not work correctly

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest version of the gem? The breakpointer version is no longer the official branch. Check https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor instead.